# Shell - how to access arguments passed as flags

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want a shell script that can take advantage of a few optional flags in this style:

`script.sh --foo "foo message" --bar "bar message"`

`script.sh --foo "foo message"`

`script.sh --bar "bar message"`

`script.sh --bar "bar message" --foo "foo message"`

What would be the simplest methods of accessing these values (ex: "foo message" and "bar message" by their flag names (ex: foo and bar) ?

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()

while test $# -gt 0; do
        case $1 in
        --foo) foo_msg=$2; shift;;
        --bar) bar_msg=$2; shift;;
        *) args+=($1);;
        esac
        shift
done
set -- "${args[@]}"

echo "remainging args: $@"
echo "foo_msg=$foo_msg"
echo "bar_msg=$bar_msg"
```

If you're using a shell without arrays, it's more difficult to retain the other arguments, but you can usually just consume them in a similar loop.